# Unable to run "vue-cli-service serve" [vue 3]

Tags: vue.js, npm, npm-install, package.json, vuejs3

**PROBLEM**

I'm trying to update packages and ran `ncu -u` once I did that I ran `npm install` to apply the new updates but it wouldn't work. It appear that it gave me issues with `eslint`??? Though I tried replicating the problem so I could post the error here and I can't seem to get it but if I remember correctly I had to do `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`. Anyways once I applied that it installs but once I try running `npm run serve` I get an error.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I've checked the versions of each package and they all are updated to the most recent version. I've deleted the "package-lock.json" and "node_modules" and reinstalled them. I'm pretty stumped what it could be. I looked up on some other stackoverflow posts mentioning about clearing the cache too but that didn't work.

**CONSOLE** (when running `npm run serve`)

```
PS C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc> npm run serve

> project-cc@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude) in {
  "exclude": [
    null
  ],
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "C:\\Users\\vdcam\\Documents\\GitHub\\project-cc\\node_modules\\cache-loader\\dist\\cjs.js",
      "options": {
        "cacheDirectory": "C:\\Users\\vdcam\\Documents\\GitHub\\project-cc\\node_modules\\.cache\\babel-loader",
        "cacheIdentifier": "39d06afa"
      },
      "ident": "clonedRuleSet-38.use[0]"
    },
    {
      "loader": "C:\\Users\\vdcam\\Documents\\GitHub\\project-cc\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\lib\\index.js",
      "options": "undefined",
      "ident": "undefined"
    }
  ]
}
Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude) in 
{
  "exclude": [
    null
  ],
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "C:\\Users\\vdcam\\Documents\\GitHub\\project-cc\\node_modules\\cache-loader\\dist\\cjs.js",
      "options": {
        "cacheDirectory": "C:\\Users\\vdcam\\Documents\\GitHub\\project-cc\\node_modules\\.cache\\babel-loader",
        "cacheIdentifier": "39d06afa"
      },
      "ident": "clonedRuleSet-38.use[0]"
    },
    {
      "loader": "C:\\Users\\vdcam\\Documents\\GitHub\\project-cc\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\lib\\index.js",
      "options": "undefined",
      "ident": "undefined"
    }
  ]
}
    at checkResourceSource (C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:167:11)
    at Function.normalizeRule (C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:198:4)
    at C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:110:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalizeRules (C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:109:17)
    at new RuleSet (C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:104:24)
    at new NormalModuleFactory (C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:115:18)
    at Compiler.createNormalModuleFactory (C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:636:31)
    at Compiler.newCompilationParams (C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:653:30)
    at Compiler.compile (C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:661:23)
    at C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:77:18
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:22:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Watching._go (C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:41:32)
    at C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:33:9
    at Compiler.readRecords (C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:529:11)
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c vue-cli-service serve

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vdcam\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-24T03_03_44_891Z-debug.log
```

**DEBUG LOG** ("npm run serve")

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\vdcam\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'run',
0 verbose cli   'serve'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.7.0
2 info using node@v12.16.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\vdcam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\vdcam\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\vdcam\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 8ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 8ms
19 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
20 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 2ms
21 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 2ms
22 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
23 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 0ms
24 timing npm:load Completed in 14ms
25 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
26 timing command:run Completed in 4496ms
27 verbose stack Error: command failed
27 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vdcam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
27 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
27 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
27 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
28 verbose pkgid project-cc@0.1.0
29 verbose cwd C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc
30 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
31 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\vdcam\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "serve"
32 verbose node v12.16.1
33 verbose npm  v7.7.0
34 error code 1
35 error path C:\Users\vdcam\Documents\GitHub\project-cc
36 error command failed
37 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c vue-cli-service serve
38 verbose exit 1
```

I would appreciate the help very much!!! Thank You!

Comment: Sure! Here is the repo! [Repo Link](https://github.com/VictorCam/project-cc) (note the repo might not be up to date since I changed some things recently)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple issues:

- Your project depends on `vue-cli-service` 4.x (which only uses Webpack 4) and on `webpack` 5. For Webpack 5, `vue-cli-service` 5.x is required. Note `@babel/eslint-parser` is also needed, and you'll have to configure `parserOptions.parser` to match. See `package.json` below.
- No need for dev dependency on `webpack`, `webpack-cli`, or `webpack-bundle-analyzer`, since `vue-cli-service` already depends on `webpack` and `webpack-bundle-analyzer` (which pulls them in transitively), and `webpack-cli` is not used in your project.

These dependencies should fix the issue:

```js
// package.json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.7",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.8.0",
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

[GitHub PR](https://github.com/VictorCam/project-cc/pull/1)

Comment: Wow appreciate that you went above and beyond to even make a pull request. I did not know that vue-cli-service came bundled with those things. That was very useful information to know. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

fix this was to revert changes in my package-lock.json.

Then a `npm prune` to remove unuseful packages and `npm update` to be up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion so I ran ```npm prune``` then ```npm update``` and I ended up getting the original error I was getting [SnapShot Link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/824125475383148557/824125499247951872/unknown.png)

Comment: `npm cache clean --force` use this command & try again

Comment: Alright I have ran ```npm cache clean --force``` and it worked fine. Though when I ran ```npm run serve``` I got this error. Which looks similar to my initial error [SnapShot Link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/824125475383148557/824135271037141032/unknown.png)